# Next element when two levels up in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I'm trying to create a tab functionality in jQuery.

**My HTML code looks like this:**

```
    <div class="feature__content">
            <h3 class="feature__content__toptitle"><?php the_sub_field('feature_top_title'); ?></h3>
            <h2 class="feature__content__title"><?php the_sub_field('feature_title'); ?></h2>


            <div class="feature__content__tabs">
                <span class="feature__content__tabs__selector" data-selector="overview">Overview</span>
                <span class="feature__content__tabs__selector" data-selector="features">Features</span>
            </div>

            <div class="feature__content__target" data-target="overview">
                <?php the_sub_field('feature_overview'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="feature__content__target" data-target="features">
                features slider here
            </div>
    </div>
```

When I click on the span with `data-selector="overview"`, the div with `data-target="overview"` must be shown. And when I click on features, the features target must be shown.

I honestly don't know how to go a few levels up and then select a specific with with a data-attribute.

**My jQuery code already looks like this:**

```
jQuery('.feature__content__target:last-child()').hide();

jQuery('.feature__content__tabs__selector').on('click', function(e) {
    var selector = jQuery(this).data('selector');
    var targets = jQuery('feature__content__target');
    var container = jQuery(this).closest('.feature__content');
    var target = container.find('div[data-target="' + selector + '"]');

    console.log(selector);

    targets.removeClass('show');
    target.addClass('show');    
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to get `div.feature__content` with `jQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

and [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```js
jQuery('.feature__content__tabs__selector').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var selector = jQuery(this).data('selector');

  jQuery(this).closest('.feature__content').find('div[data-target="'+ selector +'"]').toggle();
});
```

```css
[data-selector="overview"]{
  color: green;
}
[data-selector="features"]{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature__content">
  <h3 class="feature__content__toptitle"><?php the_sub_field('feature_top_title'); ?></h3>
  <h2 class="feature__content__title"><?php the_sub_field('feature_title'); ?></h2>


  <div class="feature__content__tabs">
      <span class="feature__content__tabs__selector" data-selector="overview">Overview</span>
      <span class="feature__content__tabs__selector" data-selector="features">Features</span>
  </div>

  <div class="feature__content__overview" data-target="overview">
      overview here
  </div>
  <div class="feature__content__features" data-target="features">
      features slider here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.closest` to navigate to the nearest ancestor of the target which has the `.feature__content` class, and from that, `.find` the element with the matching `data-target`:

```js
jQuery('.feature__content__tabs__selector').on('click', function(e) {
  var selector = jQuery(this).data('selector');
  var container = $(this).closest('.feature__content');
  var target = container.find('div[data-target="' + selector + '"]')
  target.toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature__content">
  <h3 class="feature__content__toptitle">
    <?php the_sub_field('feature_top_title'); ?>
  </h3>
  <h2 class="feature__content__title">
    <?php the_sub_field('feature_title'); ?>
  </h2>


  <div class="feature__content__tabs">
    <span class="feature__content__tabs__selector" data-selector="overview">Overview</span>
    <span class="feature__content__tabs__selector" data-selector="features">Features</span>
  </div>

  <div class="feature__content__overview" data-target="overview">
    feature overview
  </div>
  <div class="feature__content__features" data-target="features">
    features slider here
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, of course, you could call `.parent()` twice instead of using `closest`:

```js
jQuery('.feature__content__tabs__selector').on('click', function(e) {
  var selector = jQuery(this).data('selector');
  var container = $(this).parent().parent();
  var target = container.find('div[data-target="' + selector + '"]')
  target.toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature__content">
  <h3 class="feature__content__toptitle">
    <?php the_sub_field('feature_top_title'); ?>
  </h3>
  <h2 class="feature__content__title">
    <?php the_sub_field('feature_title'); ?>
  </h2>


  <div class="feature__content__tabs">
    <span class="feature__content__tabs__selector" data-selector="overview">Overview</span>
    <span class="feature__content__tabs__selector" data-selector="features">Features</span>
  </div>

  <div class="feature__content__overview" data-target="overview">
    feature overview
  </div>
  <div class="feature__content__features" data-target="features">
    features slider here
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, with your new HTML, if you want to toggle with classes instead, then just use those classes, and not `.show()` / `.hide()` (an element toggled with those methods will not be affected by classes that make an element visible or not).

Note that you need to use `.` before a class to indicate that you want to search for an element with that class. (Your `var targets = jQuery('feature__content__target');` will look for elements with a *tag name* of `feature__content__target`)

```js
jQuery('.feature__content__tabs__selector').on('click', function(e) {
  var selector = jQuery(this).data('selector');
  var targets = jQuery('.feature__content__target');
  var container = jQuery(this).closest('.feature__content');
  var target = container.find('div[data-target="' + selector + '"]');

  console.log(selector);

  targets.removeClass('show');
  target.addClass('show');
});
```

```css
.feature__content__target {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature__content">
  <h3 class="feature__content__toptitle">
    <?php the_sub_field('feature_top_title'); ?>
  </h3>
  <h2 class="feature__content__title">
    <?php the_sub_field('feature_title'); ?>
  </h2>


  <div class="feature__content__tabs">
    <span class="feature__content__tabs__selector" data-selector="overview">Overview</span>
    <span class="feature__content__tabs__selector" data-selector="features">Features</span>
  </div>

  <div class="feature__content__target" data-target="overview">
    feature overview here
  </div>
  <div class="feature__content__target" data-target="features">
    features slider here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right director.

I've changed my code a little bit, so that the class show is added the the current visible div.
I've added var targets = jQuery('feature__content__target'); and this: targets.removeClass('show');
        target.addClass('show');    

But it doesn't remove anything. When I test it in the console, it works perfectly.

Update my question above.

Comment: Ok, see edit, if you want to use classes, best to use classes alone rather than `.show()` / `.hide()`

Comment: Yes, I got it :-) Thank you for your help.